many to many serializers error in post api
i have many-to-many relationship between Movie and Person through Cast. I use CastSerializer to create post method to create new movie and new cast relationship, but when call post method, response return AttributeError.
I want my post body like this:
{
  ...
  "title": "string",
  "genres": [
    0
  ],
  "cast": [
    {
      "charactor": "string",
      "cast": 0,
      "order": 2147483647
    }
  ]
}

AttributeError at /movie/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `cast` on serializer `MoviesSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Movie` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'person'.

this is models:
class Movie(models.Model):
    ...
    cast = models.ManyToManyField(Person,related_name='cast_movies', through="Cast")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class Cast(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,null=False,blank=False)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='casts')
    cast = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='person')
    charactor = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True,default='')
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cast.name + " ("+ self.movie.title + ")"

serializers:
class CastSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cast
        fields = ['charactor','cast','order']    
    
class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genres = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Genre.objects.all(),slug_field='id'
    )
    cast = CastSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [ ...,'cast']
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        genres_data = validated_data.pop('genres', []) 
        
        cast_data = validated_data.pop('cast', []) 
        movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for cast in cast_data:
            Cast.objects.create(movie_id = movie.id,**cast)
        genresInstances = []
        for genre in genres_data:
            genresInstances.append(genre)
        
        movie.genres.set(genresInstances)
        return movie


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

You did not post your full model, payload and serializer fields. 'Movie' object has no attribute 'person'. indicates that somewhere in that obscurity you are calling a field that does not exist.
